# How to get original inner-elements for a component

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am writing a simple component "special-div" that may look like the following in my markup...

```
<special-div>
   <img src="logo.jpg" />
   <div>This is some random markup</div>
   <p>Anything could be inside the special div</p>
</special-div>
```

I want to capture everything inside my component's tags and reuse those elements in my component's template. Let's say my component simply becomes a div with some title-text to it.. at it's most basic it would do this..

```
<special-div></special-div>
```

would yield...

```
<div>
    <p>I am a special div</p>
</div>
```

.. what I can't figure out how to do is GET the original elements so they can also appear inside my new template. Example...

```
<special-div>
   <img src="logo.jpg" />
   <div>This is some random markup</div>
   <p>Anything could be inside the special div</p>
</special-div>
```

..become..

```
<div>
   <p>I am a special div</p>

   <img src="logo.jpg" />
   <div>This is some random markup</div>
   <p>Anything could be inside the special div</p>
</div>
```

Comment: did you look at `Transclusion ` using `ng-content`

Comment: That does the trick. Way too simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to achieve what you want can be done with something called **content projection** (renamed from *transclusion* as it was known in AngularJS).

Baiscally, it's like you leave a "hole" inside your template that you can fill in from the outside.

---

Your `SpecialDivComponent` would have a **template** such as the following.

```
<p>I'm special because I always have this tag!</p>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

You would **use this component** like this.

```
<special-div>
  <p>Hello there!</p>
  <b>Nice to meet ya!</b>
</special-div>
```

The **result** would be the following markup.

```
<special-div>
  <p>I'm special because I always have this tag!</p>
  <p>Hello there!</p>
  <b>Nice to meet ya!</b>
</special-div>
```

Comment: Man, that was wayyyy to simple. Thanks!